# Tableau Service Management vs Tableau Server

Tags: tableau-api

I am a beginner of Tableau.
I have gone through the Trusted Authentication on Tableau online help.

But I found that to add the web server IP address to https://tsm-computer-name:8850.
And I found that Tableau Server domain and Ip address are also required.

So I just want to know the following questions.

Are Tableau Server and Tableau Service Management on different computers?
If so, where should TSM be installed and how?
How do I create a TSM credential (admin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They way I differentiate two, is TSM (Tableau Services Manager) is the backend admin account and is used for configuring and licensing Tableau Server.

The Tableau Server Administrator account is used to administer the content published to Tableau Server, user/ groups and permissions.

TSM is automatically installed when installing Tableau Server, and the account used to log into TSM is typically the account being used to remote into the machine hosting Tableau Server. I found a decent guide using their online help.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/sign_in_tsm.htm

Also, a good way to verify which user can/is being used for TSM is to try running a TSM command from CLI. For example, running ' TSM Status -v ' should prompt you for a password for X user, this is what you would log into the TSM UI with.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau Services Manager (TSM) replaces multiple tools from previous versions of Tableau Server: Tableau Server Configuration, tabadmin command line, Tableau Server
Monitor, and Manage License Keys.

Online guide gives more details.
https://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/whitepapers/tsm_slideshare.pdf